# Which is better CPU?

Tags: central-processing-unit

I have two linodes. Both are 4 cores with 8GB RAM. I see different CPUs on both the linodes. I use one for production and one for test. Below is the CPU information I see. Please advise which one should I retain and use it for production. Which CPU is better?

```
Linode one:
processor : 0
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model : 62
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz
stepping : 4
microcode : 0x1
cpu MHz : 2799.992
cache size : 16384 KB
physical id : 0
siblings : 1
core id : 0
cpu cores : 1
apicid : 0
initial apicid : 0
fpu : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp : yes
flags : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm pti fsgsbase tsc_adjust smep erms xsaveopt arat
bugs : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf
bogomips : 5602.31
clflush size : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management

Linode Two:
processor : 0
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model : 85
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6148 CPU @ 2.40GHz
stepping : 4
microcode : 0x1
cpu MHz : 2400.000
cache size : 16384 KB
physical id : 0
siblings : 1
core id : 0
cpu cores : 1
apicid : 0
initial apicid : 0
fpu : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp : yes
flags : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves arat pku ospke
bugs : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf
bogomips : 4801.00
clflush size : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: Do you have these as bare metal machines? Or are they virtual machines where you share the CPU with other instances? If the latter, we can't possibly answer without knowing, for example, how many cores your instance is allowed to use.

Comment: These are virtual machines. My plan has 4 cores.

Comment: So you asked the wrong question. You don't want to know which is the better CPU, you want to know which CPU has faster cores. (If one has twice as many cores as the other, but the other has 15% faster cores, you want the one with the faster cores, not the one with twice as many cores.)

Comment: You are correct. Both run Magento 2 with 200 visitors per day. 1000 SKUs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xeon Gold 6148 has much faster cores than the E5-2680v2, primarily because it is four years newer. So that's the one you want. It also has twice as many cores, but that doesn't help you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So Xeon Gold is better for Magento 2 with 200 visitors per day. 1000 SKUs. Can you please confirm?

Comment: The CPU is better for that task if you are limited to four cores on it. However, I can imagine theoretical cases where the other would be better. For example, say the Xeon Gold has lots of other customers on it who are using lots of memory bandwidth and the E5-2680v2 is idle so all the memory bandwidth is yours. But judging just from the CPUs and the fact that you have four cores, yes, the Xeon Gold would be better for almost any application. (I'm also assuming both physical machines are sensibly configured, for example, all memory channels populated.)